# How to optimize SQL query with subqueries

Tags: sql-server

I have this query that is taking a long time to execute. I would like to know how to optimize it. What slows it down are the addition subqueries.

This is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
     dbo.Ventas.IdVenta, dbo.Ventas.CodigoVenta, dbo.Ventas.Fecha_Alta, dbo.M_Operadores.Nombre + ' ' + dbo.M_Operadores.Apellidos AS Operador, SUBSTRING(dbo.Ventas.Cliente, 0, CHARINDEX(CHAR(13), dbo.Ventas.Cliente)) 
     AS Cliente, dbo.M_Centros.Centro,
         (SELECT        SUM(LineaImporte) AS Expr1
           FROM            dbo.Ventas_Detalle
           WHERE        (IdVenta = dbo.Ventas.IdVenta)) - dbo.Ventas.Redondeo AS Importe,
         (SELECT        ISNULL(SUM(dbo.Movimientos_Caja_Detalle.Ajuste), 0) AS Ajuste
           FROM            dbo.Movimientos_Caja_Detalle INNER JOIN
                                     dbo.Movimientos_Caja ON dbo.Movimientos_Caja_Detalle.IdMovimientoCaja = dbo.Movimientos_Caja.IdMovimientoCaja
           WHERE        (dbo.Movimientos_Caja.IdVenta = dbo.Ventas.IdVenta)) AS Ajuste,
         (SELECT        ISNULL(SUM(Movimientos_Caja_Detalle_2.Importe), 0) AS Cobrado
           FROM            dbo.Movimientos_Caja_Detalle AS Movimientos_Caja_Detalle_2 INNER JOIN
                                     dbo.Movimientos_Caja AS Movimientos_Caja_2 ON Movimientos_Caja_Detalle_2.IdMovimientoCaja = Movimientos_Caja_2.IdMovimientoCaja
           WHERE        (Movimientos_Caja_2.IdVenta = dbo.Ventas.IdVenta) OR
                                     (Movimientos_Caja_2.CodigoSobre = dbo.Ventas.CodigoSobre) AND (Movimientos_Caja_2.IdTipoMov_Caja = 7)) AS Cobrado,
         (SELECT        SUM(LineaImporte) AS Expr1
           FROM            dbo.Ventas_Detalle AS Ventas_Detalle_1
           WHERE        (IdVenta = dbo.Ventas.IdVenta)) - dbo.Ventas.Redondeo -
         (SELECT        ISNULL(SUM(Movimientos_Caja_Detalle_1.Importe), 0) AS Cobrado
           FROM            dbo.Movimientos_Caja_Detalle AS Movimientos_Caja_Detalle_1 INNER JOIN
                                     dbo.Movimientos_Caja AS Movimientos_Caja_1 ON Movimientos_Caja_Detalle_1.IdMovimientoCaja = Movimientos_Caja_1.IdMovimientoCaja
           WHERE        (Movimientos_Caja_1.IdVenta = dbo.Ventas.IdVenta) OR
                                     (Movimientos_Caja_1.CodigoSobre = dbo.Ventas.CodigoSobre) AND (Movimientos_Caja_1.IdTipoMov_Caja = 7)) AS Pendiente,
         (SELECT        Importe AS expr1
           FROM            dbo.Vales
           WHERE        (IdVentaEmision = dbo.Ventas.IdVenta)) AS Vale, dbo.Ventas.CodigoSobre, dbo.Ventas.FechaTerminado, dbo.Ventas.IdCentro_Alta AS IdCentro, dbo.Ventas.FechaEntregado, dbo.Ventas.IdOperador, 
     dbo.Ventas.FacturaVenta, dbo.Ventas.FechaFactura, dbo.Ventas.EstadoFactura, dbo.Ventas.TipoFactura
FROM         dbo.Ventas INNER JOIN
             dbo.M_Operadores ON dbo.Ventas.IdOperador = dbo.M_Operadores.IdOperador INNER JOIN
             dbo.M_Centros ON dbo.Ventas.IdCentro_Alta = dbo.M_Centros.IdCentro
```

---

This is the code after changes based on comments:

```
SELECT  
    V.IdVenta, V.CodigoVenta, V.Fecha_Alta, MO.Nombre + ' ' + MO.Apellidos AS Operador, SUBSTRING(V.Cliente, 0, CHARINDEX(CHAR(13), V.Cliente)) 
    AS Cliente, MC.Centro,
        (SELECT        SUM(LineaImporte) AS Expr1
        FROM            Ventas_Detalle
        WHERE        (IdVenta = V.IdVenta)) - V.Redondeo AS Importe,
        (SELECT        ISNULL(SUM(Movimientos_Caja_Detalle.Ajuste), 0) AS Ajuste
        FROM            Movimientos_Caja_Detalle INNER JOIN
                                    Movimientos_Caja ON Movimientos_Caja_Detalle.IdMovimientoCaja = Movimientos_Caja.IdMovimientoCaja
        WHERE        (Movimientos_Caja.IdVenta = V.IdVenta)) AS Ajuste,
        (SELECT        ISNULL(SUM(Movimientos_Caja_Detalle_2.Importe), 0) AS Cobrado
        FROM            Movimientos_Caja_Detalle AS Movimientos_Caja_Detalle_2 INNER JOIN
                                    Movimientos_Caja AS Movimientos_Caja_2 ON Movimientos_Caja_Detalle_2.IdMovimientoCaja = Movimientos_Caja_2.IdMovimientoCaja
        WHERE        (Movimientos_Caja_2.IdVenta = V.IdVenta) OR
                                    (Movimientos_Caja_2.CodigoSobre = V.CodigoSobre) AND (Movimientos_Caja_2.IdTipoMov_Caja = 7)) AS Cobrado,
        (SELECT        SUM(LineaImporte) AS Expr1
        FROM            Ventas_Detalle AS Ventas_Detalle_1
        WHERE        (IdVenta = V.IdVenta)) - V.Redondeo -
        (SELECT        ISNULL(SUM(Movimientos_Caja_Detalle_1.Importe), 0) AS Cobrado
        FROM            Movimientos_Caja_Detalle AS Movimientos_Caja_Detalle_1 INNER JOIN
                                    Movimientos_Caja AS Movimientos_Caja_1 ON Movimientos_Caja_Detalle_1.IdMovimientoCaja = Movimientos_Caja_1.IdMovimientoCaja
        WHERE        (Movimientos_Caja_1.IdVenta = V.IdVenta) OR
                                    (Movimientos_Caja_1.CodigoSobre = V.CodigoSobre) AND (Movimientos_Caja_1.IdTipoMov_Caja = 7)) AS Pendiente,
        (SELECT        Importe AS expr1
        FROM            Vales
        WHERE        (IdVentaEmision = V.IdVenta)) AS Vale, V.CodigoSobre, V.FechaTerminado, V.IdCentro_Alta AS IdCentro, V.FechaEntregado, V.IdOperador, 
    V.FacturaVenta, V.FechaFactura, V.EstadoFactura, V.TipoFactura
FROM            Ventas V INNER JOIN
                M_Operadores MO ON V.IdOperador = MO.IdOperador INNER JOIN
                M_Centros MC ON V.IdCentro_Alta = MC.IdCentro
```

Comment: FYI [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) and should be avoided. You are far better off aliasing your objects in the `FROM` and using those to qualify your columns. This avoids the use of a feature that will be deprecated and possibly removed in a future version, and makes your code much more succinct and readable. For your query, using some *good* aliases would *really* improve it

Comment: I suspect that you *don't* want the subqueries here, if i am honest. Also do you *need* that `DISTINCT`? That is very likely to be *very* expensive in the above.

Comment: Thanks for the input @larnu. I have applied the changes you mention but the query is still slow. Is there a way that the SUM functions in the select can be made faster?

Comment: As these are all fairly simple calculations a table valued function might be an option to make execution faster. Check out https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-inline-table-valued-function/ for a starting lesson. Normally I find iTVF performing better than subselects